# Does the Silverlight Navigation template work with running out of browser?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

Does the Silverlight Navigation template work when running out of browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it does.

And you can use the NavigationServices functions to create a custom "Back" or "Forward" button

great example here : [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: ? broken link - I get "Unable to Service Request"

Comment: double checked my link and it works.  Changed my post for a coded hyperlink

Answer (score 1):

Create a fresh Navigation Application, open the properties page.  On the Silverlight tab select "Enable running application out of the browser", switch to the Debug tab, select Out-of-Browser application, change the project in the combo-box to the current silverlight project.

Hit Run, click About, Does it work?